# Finding vector for a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix $A$

$$\left (\begin{array}{l}6&1&0\\1&0&6\\0&6&1\end{array}\right)$$

which is indefinite.

I want to ask how I would find two vectors $X$ and $Y$ such that

$(X)^TAX<0$ and $(Y)^TAY<0$

I am thiking this is by determinants but am not sure.

Comment: Shouldn’t that be $X^TAX\gt0$?

Comment: I’m still curious to see what exactly you mean by “by determinants” here. Expand on that in your question, please.

Comment: I probably never understood Sylvester criterion too well. Reading my textbook, I assume the determinants is part of finding the criterion. Maybe I am not thinking right

Answer (score 0):

well...  take a column vector $Z$ with value $Z^T DZ$ with the sign you want, that is the same as $(PZ)^T H (PZ)$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 6 & 36 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 6 \\ 
0 & 6 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  &  - 6 \\ 
0 & 1 & 36 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 217 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

If you prefer, you may orthogonally diagonalize $R^THR = D_1,$ with $R^TR = I,$ as the eigenvalues  are not that bad, $7, \sqrt{31}, -\sqrt{31}$

Answer (score 0):

For this particular matrix, it’s not terribly hard to find the required vectors by inspection. The corresponding quadratic form is $6x_1^2+2x_1x_2+12x_2x_3+x_3^2$, so any nonzero vector with no negative entries will do for $X$.

Moving now to $Y$, the only terms that can be negative are $2x_1x_2$ and $12x_2x_3$ so the sign of $x_2$ must differ from that of $x_1$ or $x_3$, or both. To simplify things, set, say, $x_1=0$. Now you need to choose $x_2$ and $x_3$ such that $12x_2x_3+x_3^2\lt0$. Taking $x_3=1$ leaves $12x_2+1\lt0$, so to finish choose $x_2$ accordingly.